# I want it to open automatically in my matmenu when the page is opened

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular14

I want my material menu to open automatically when my page is opened, but because I am not click, "trigger" is undefined

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'openMenu')

```
 @ViewChild('menuTrigger') trigger;
    ngOnInit() {  
    if (this.headerService.isCookieDown = "0") {
          this.trigger.openMenu()
        } 
    }



 <button mat-button #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger" [matMenuTriggerFor]="infomenu"><img bell.svg"></button>



 <mat-menu class="info-menu" style="max-width: 400px !important;" [hasBackdrop]="false" #infomenu="matMenu"> 
html codes..
 </mat-menu>
```

Comment: Consider moving the open menu call to the [`ngAfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-view-changes) lifecycle hook, rather than `ngOnInit`.

Comment: thank you sir it worked if you reply as a post I can mark it as correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Implement the [ngAfterViewInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#responding-to-view-changes) lifecycle hook and make the `openMenu` call in `ngAfterViewInit`, like below.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {  
    if (this.headerService.isCookieDown = "0") {
      this.trigger.openMenu()
    } 
}
```